# Store multiple user identities

Tags: asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.1, google-authentication

I implemented cookie authentication and google one. And I have this problem:
assume I'm logged in with cookie identity and I want to link google account to ASP identity account. But when I successfully log in to google account I see that I was logged out from cookie identity because it was replaced by Google identity. And I can't link google account because now I'm out of ASP identity account. One possible solution is to store account data for example in TempData, and after google login perform ASP login and then link two accounts. But that's a trick.

So the question is could I store both identities cookie and google?

Comment: Are you doing a custom integration with Google? If you use the Google Authentication built-in to Identity, you won't have any issues. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/google-logins?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: @ChrisPratt , did exactly as in this article, but I have this use case: User tries to link a google account but the account is already linked.  User can't use this identity and default (cookie) identity is lost because of being replaced by google identity, so I have to send an extra request to authenticate the user again with saved token. I'm just trying to avoid this extra step